# Going from one Dialog to the next

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've got a main LuisDialog that is used to determine the user's intent. Based on that I start another Dialog (from a set of utilitiy Dialogs) to ask the questions of the user that are then used to do some kind of process. All that is well and good.

What I would like to do, and which I am struggling with, is as follows.

When the utility Dialog completes, it calls the appropriate completion task in the main LuisDialog. In that completion task I use the data from the utility dialog to call a web service and obtain some data. Some of data is then displayed to the user. That all works fine. I want to extend this so if multiple records are returned from the web service I would like to pass some of that data to a different utility dialog, which would ask the user further questions based on the web service data. Hope that makes sense.

I've tried to run the second utility dialog but it never seems to run. It seems to go into it but doesn't display anything to the user.

Any suggestions on what would be the preferred method of doing this scenario would be gratefully received.

Comment: Can you show how you are running your second dialog?

Comment: I've managed to sort it out. As it turned out, I was also passing a variable into the new dialog and I needed to make it Serializable. Once I did that, it all worked as I was expecting it to work.